# How to update custom Rails route param value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bunch of Rails models where the resources are looked up by a custom field - `username` in the case of users, `slug` for some others, etc - and it all works well for viewing these resources and updating any attribute other than the one used for routing.

A typical route involved in this situation looks like this:

```rb
resources :profiles, param: :username, except: :destroy do
  get :applications, controller: :profile_applications, action: :index
  put :tags, controller: :profile_tags, action: :update
end
```

If I want to update the slug / username, however, the value will not change.

Is the attribute used in the route definition somehow protected from being changed? I understand that it is for `id`, but model relationships do not revolve around these custom fields, the foreign keys are still `id` all across the app.

How can I overwrite a username based on user input?

Comment: "If I want to update the slug / username, however, the value will not change." - show the code, please (controller, anything called in the controller action that may change the execution flow etc)

Comment: You should look at the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) before you spend a bunch of time reinventing the slugging/vanity url wheel. It has an optional slug history feature that ensures that you don't get 404's if the slug were to change - it does so by storing the old slugs in a separate table.

Comment: "Is the attribute used in the route definition somehow protected from being changed?" - absolutely not. Rails doesn't make any of your attributes write protected unless you explicitly do so. There also is  no actual link between your model attributes and the routes. Rails is convention driven - its not artificial intellegence.

Comment: "How can I overwrite a username based on user input?". You just do it. Rails has no concept of usernames and if an attribute isn't changing as expected its down to bugs in your application.

Comment: @max I log out the patch request that I'm sending to the Rails API, and it contains the correct value, the one entered by the user. Logging out `params` in the controller, however, is using the old value, the one passed to the URL.

Comment: If only there was something like logs and code that could be used to communicate your problem in a way that other people can understand, replicate and fix... ;)